# Cannot Vertically Center h3 element within div

Tags: html, css

I want my h3 element to be vertically centred within the div element. I tried several solutions but any of those didn't work. Could anyone figure it out for me where I am doing wrong?

Below is my html and CSS code snippet.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    <h3 id="test_h3">This is a text</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    text-align: center;
}
#test_h3{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
#test{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    text-align: center;
}
#test_h3{
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <h3 id="test_h3">This is a text</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: 99% of the questions are already answered. Please try to find it before posting a repeated question.

This is also a proper answer in w3schools    
resources :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: I am sorry for asking naive question. I am a beginner level programmer in web development. That's why I could not figure out how to do this. I should have searched more. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Don't be sorry. No question is naive nor i have commented to let you down. My sole purpose is to make understand that you should search more.. Search for answers and then finally post a question. **The more you find answer yourself the better developer you become.**

Comment: This is true Bro: The more one finds answer his/herself the better developer the person would become. Thanks a lot for your great advice! :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: center` is a joke. Make your div a flexbox, this is simple and works everytime

```
.your-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Where `align-items: center` centers the element vertically

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tracer69. This works now. No where I found this 3 lines of code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:100px
}
#test_h3{
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <h3 id="test_h3">This is a text</h3>
</div>
```

you can use  `line-height` css to get this. check out my snippet

Comment: a pleasure to help, can you accept the answer please, happy coding:-D

Comment: I wish I could! I have the option to accept only one answer. So, I accepted the first one. I have upvoted your answer. Thanks again for answering my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case but you will encounter more complex layouts in which flex-box will shine. I recommend you to use flex-box:

```css
#test{
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#test_h3{
   display: flex;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <h3 id="test_h3">This is a text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`center` is not a valid value for CSS property `vertical-align`. However, `middle` is

```css
#test{
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    text-align: center;
}
#test_h3{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <h3 id="test_h3">This is a text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using this code

```
#test {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Please do not just paste working code, but explain what you did. This won't help him as much

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Will note that next time